# Find overlapping matches and submatches using regular expressions in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.4, string-matching, dna-sequence

I have a string of characters (a DNA sequence) with a regular expression I designed to filter out possible matches, `(?:ATA|ATT)[ATCGN]{144,16563}(?:AGA|AGG|TAA|TAG)`. Later I apply two filter conditions:

1. The sequence must be divisible by 3, `len(match) % 3 == 0`, and
2. There must be no stop codon (`['AGA', 'AGG', 'TAA', 'TAG']`) before the end of the string, `not any(substring in list(sliced(match[:-3], 3)) for substring in [x.replace("U", "T") for x in stop_codons])`.

However, when I apply these filters, I get no matches at all (before the filters I get around ~200 matches. The way I'm searching for substrings in the full sequence is by running `re.findall(regex, genome_fasta, overlapped=True)`, because matches could be submatches of other matches.

Is there something about regular expressions that I'm misunderstanding? To my knowledge, after the filters I should still have matches.

If there's anything else I need to add please let me know! (I'm using the `regex` package for Python 3.4, not the standard `re` package, because it has no overlap support).

EDIT 1:

Per comment: I'm looking for ORFs in the mitochondrial genome, but only considering those at least 150 nucleotides (characters) in length. Considering overlap is important because a match could include the first start codon in the string and the last stop codon in the string, but there could be another start codon in the middle. For example:

- Given "ATAAAGCCATTTACCGTACATAGCACATTATAACCAACAAACCTACCCACCCTTAACTAG", matches should be "ATAAAGCCATTTACCGTACATAGCACATTATAACCAACAAACCTACCCACCCTTAACTAG" but also "ATAAAGCCATTTACCGTACATAGCACATTATAA", since both "TAG" and "TAA" are stop codons.

EDIT 2:

Totally, misunderstood comment, full code for method is:

```
typical_regex = r"%s[ATCGN]{%s,%s}%s" % (proc_start_codons, str(minimum_orf_length - 6), str(maximum_orf_length - 6), proc_stop_codons)

typical_fwd_matches = []
    if re.search(typical_regex, genome_fasta, overlapped=True):
        for match in re.findall(typical_regex, genome_fasta, overlapped=True):
            if len(match) % 3 == 0:
                if not any(substring in list(sliced(match[:-3], 3)) for substring in [x.replace("U", "T") for x in stop_codons]):
                    typical_fwd_matches.append(match)

print(typical_fwd_matches)
```

The `typical_fwd_matches` array is empty and the regex is rendered as `(?:ATA|ATT)[ATCGN]{144,16563}(?:AGA|AGG|TAA|TAG)` when printed to console/file.

Comment: Give examples, not code talk. Also, what do you mean by _overlap_ ??

Comment: @sin my bad! Added example and clarified overlap. Let me know if I should add more!

Comment: I think sln is asking you to show some code.  You're telling us what you think you're doing, but not showing is the code so we can verify you're doing what you think you are.  Can you show us a short, complete example of your code that applies the regex @ filter to this string?

Comment: My best guess `(?=((?:ATA|ATT)(?:(?!AGA|AGG|TAA|TAG)[ATCGN]{3})+))` where $1 contains the item. And, the standard re does this.

Comment: @Gerrat added another comment, sorry! sin I'm not sure what you mean by $1 in this context?

Comment: The overlap idea, is more of a subset idea. But that is controlled by quantifiers and only minimum or maximum. You might have to construct a new regex _after each match_ that sets the max length to 3 less than the last match length, then proceede until no more matches. Initially it would be `(?:ATA|ATT)(?:[ATCGN]{3})+(?:AGA|AGG|TAA|TAG)` then based on the last match `(?:ATA|ATT)(?:[ATCGN]{3})[0,<last match len/3 - 2>}(?:AGA|AGG|TAA|TAG)`

Comment: Ohh... Okay. I think I'm understanding what you're saying, but I'm not positive how I would implement that efficiently. Would that basically be a for loop of re.findall within a loop of re.findall which subtracts 3 each time? (Also if you want to add a brief code segment of this as an answer, I'll try to implement it and accept it) Thanks so much!

Comment: Added a code sample.

Comment: Btw, regex seems like it was made for gene sequencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it this way.
The subsets will consist of ever decreasing size of the previous matches.
That's about all you have to do.
So, it's fairly straight forward to design the regex.

The regex will only match multiples of 3 chars.
The beginning and middle are captured in group 1.
This is used for the new ***text*** value which is just the last match
minus the last 3 chars.

Regex explained:

```
 (                             # (1 start), Whole match minus last 3 chars
      (?: ATA | ATT )               # Starts with one of these 3 char sequence
      (?:                           # Cluster group
           [ATCGN]{3}                    # Any 3 char sequence consisting of these chars
      )+                            # End cluster, do 1 to many times
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?: AGA | AGG | TAA | TAG )   # Last 3 char sequence, one of these
```

Python code sample:

[Demo](http://www.pythontutor.com/live.html#code=import%20re%0A%0Ar%20%3D%20re.compile%28r%22%28%28%3F%3AATA%7CATT%29%28%3F%3A%5BATCGN%5D%7B3%7D%29%2B%29%28%3F%3AAGA%7CAGG%7CTAA%7CTAG%29%22%29%0Atext%20%3D%20%22ATAAAGCCATTTACCGTACATAGCACATTATAACCAACAAACCTACCCACCCTTAACTAG%22%0A%0Am%20%3D%20r.search%28text%29%0Awhile%20m%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28%22Found%3A%20%20%22%20%2B%20m.group%280%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20text%20%3D%20m.group%281%29%0A%20%20%20%20m%20%3D%20r.search%28text%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=17&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-live.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"((?:ATA|ATT)(?:[ATCGN]{3})+)(?:AGA|AGG|TAA|TAG)")
text = "ATAAAGCCATTTACCGTACATAGCACATTATAACCAACAAACCTACCCACCCTTAACTAG"

m = r.search(text)
while m:
    print("Found:  " + m.group(0))
    text = m.group(1)
    m = r.search(text)
```

Output:

```
Found:  ATAAAGCCATTTACCGTACATAGCACATTATAACCAACAAACCTACCCACCCTTAACTAG
Found:  ATAAAGCCATTTACCGTACATAGCACATTATAA
Found:  ATTTACCGTACATAG
```

---

Using this method, the subsets being tested are these:

ATAAAGCCATTTACCGTACATAGCACATTATAACCAACAAACCTACCCACCCTTAACTAG
ATAAAGCCATTTACCGTACATAGCACATTATAACCAACAAACCTACCCACCCTTAAC
ATAAAGCCATTTACCGTACATAGCACATTA
ATTTACCGTACA

We can benchmark the time the regex takes to match these.

```
Regex1:   ((?:ATA|ATT)(?:[ATCGN]{3})+)(?:AGA|AGG|TAA|TAG)
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    1.63 s,   1627.59 ms,   1627594 µs
Matches per sec:   92,160
```

Comment: Oh my god this is incredible! Thank you so much!